# identify 32v dc out power connector

Tags: power, connector

I am curious to know what this 32vdc power connector commonly in purple color used to power hp printers is called?

Whether it is part of any national standards worldwide? Try hard as I may on google, I am unable to find any decent standard about this connector. Is it a proprietary standard used by hp?

[image: HP 32VDC POWER CONNECTOR]

Comment: Using my best google-fu skills, couldn't find anything. Nearest type is that of an atx motherboard psu connector, cut down a tad, and making sure the orientation of the three individual plugs are identical.

Comment: Looks like a type of Molex Mini-Fit connector. It actually looks like this one here: https://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0679690001/WM4256-ND/2424539

Comment: And here is another one: http://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/67969-0001/?qs=EuyFtE1skidA7JB%252b1%2fKIcw== I am going to conclude that this is a Molex connector with manufacturer part number 67969-0001.

Comment: Hi JohnnyVegas thanks for your reply, , me thinks Jerry Hundric nailed it, he has it rightly identified, I knew it must be Molex but couldn't identify the exact one, you are a pro Jerry, thanks!